# Loading JSON data to multiple tables in BigQuery

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

My JSON looks like:

```
{
    "Key1":"Value1","Key2":"Value2","Key3":"Value3","List1":
    [
        {
            "SubKey1":"SubValue1_1","SubKey2":"SubValue1_2","SubKey3":"SubValue1_3"
        },
        {
            "SubKey1":"SubValue2_1","SubKey2":"SubValue2_2","SubKey3":"SubValue2_3"
        },
        {
            "SubKey1":"SubValue3_1","SubKey2":"SubValue3_2","SubKey3":"SubValue3_3"
        }
    ]
}
```

It loads in a single BigQuery table like this:

---

[image]

---

But I want my data to load in 2 seperate tables like:

---

[image]

---

and

---

[image]

---

Please guide on what I should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be possible if you can use the bq command line.

Presuming that your JSON file (my_json_file.json) lives in a GCS bucket (e.g. my_gcs_bucket) and the destination table my_dataset.my_destination_table, you can run the following command

```
bq load --ignore_unknown_values --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON my_dataset.my_destination_table "gs://my_gcs_bucket/my_json_file.json" ./schema.json
```

where in the schema.json, you have already selected the schema of the destination table. For instance, the following two schemas will load the data as expected:

**schema_1.json**

```
[
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "Key1",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "Key2",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "Key3",
    "type": "STRING"
  }
]
```

and **schema_2.json**

```
[
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "Key1",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "fields": [
      {
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "name": "SubKey1",
        "type": "STRING"
      },
      {
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "name": "SubKey2",
        "type": "STRING"
      },
      {
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "name": "SubKey3",
        "type": "STRING"
      }
    ],
    "mode": "REPEATED",
    "name": "List1",
    "type": "RECORD"
  }
]
```

and then

```
bq load --ignore_unknown_values --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON my_dataset.my_destination_table_1 "gs://my_gcs_bucket/my_json_file.json" ./schema_1.json

bq load --ignore_unknown_values --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON my_dataset.my_destination_table_2 "gs://my_gcs_bucket/my_json_file.json" ./schema_2.json
```

Will load two different tables based on the same JSON file

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible to do it directly while loading the data.

I would advise loading the data as it is and then executing the following queries to create tables with data in the format you need. The "cs_test" is the name of the dataset for your tables, "so" is the name of the table with loaded data:

```
CREATE TABLE cs_test.so_2 AS SELECT key1, list FROM cs_test.so AS s, unnest(s.list1) AS list;
```

The data in "so_2" would look like this:

[image]

And to create a table with the data in the format like this:

[image]

You need to execute the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE cs_test.so_1 AS SELECT key1, key2, key3 FROM cs_test.so;
```